# How do you create a smaller function from a bigger function?

Tags: c++, function, pointers

Suppose I have a function `int func(int x, int y, int z)` and I need to call it within another function 10 times, ie, `int runge(int, ... , int func(int a, int b))`. 
I know I could create 10 functions, i.e.

```
 int runge1(int a, int b) {return func(1, a, b);}
```

But, I'd like a simpler method of doing this.
Basically I want to create a function pointer as such:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
    //func would have two variables input into it, variable1, variable2
    int (*func)=func(i, variable1, variable2);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, your example about calling the function *10 times within another function` is not clarifying things at all. Perhaps by expanding a bit more (i.e. for `i = 1, 2, 3, ...`) your question would become clearer.

Comment: Thank you for the help, sorry about my question being unclear.  I need to wait a minute to accept a correct answer, but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

```
std::function<int(int,int)> f = std::bind(&func, i, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
```

This will  bind `i` to the first argument of `func` and leave the remaining arguments unbound. You can then call `f` like so:

```
f(1, 2);
```

If you want to, you can push all of your newly bound functions into a `std::vector`:

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
std::vector<std::function<int(int,int)>> funcs;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  funcs.push_back(std::bind(&func, i, _1, _2));
}
```

If you don't have C++11, there is a [`boost::bind`](http://www.boost.org/libs/bind) counterpart.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure by your description, but it looks like you're looking to curry the function.

In C++, here's a good example: [How can currying be done in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152005/how-can-currying-be-done-in-c)

Comment: that example is rather old, and those binders mentioned there are deprecated with the new standard, having `std::bind` and lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you want to know `std::function`, Lambdas and maybe `std::bind`:

```
int func(int x, int y, int z);

typedef std::function<int(int,int)> FuncT;
std::array<FuncT, 10> functions; //or whatever container suits your needs
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
  functions[i] = [=](int a, int b) { return func(i,a,b); }; //with lambdas
  functions[i] = std::bind(func, i, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2); //with bind
}
```

(I prefer lambdas, but that's a matter of taste...)