# Stopping generic C++14 `curry` function recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, functional-programming, c++14, currying

I'm trying to implement a generic `curry` function in C++14 that takes a callable object as an input parameter and allows [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

Desired syntax:

```
auto sum3 = [](int x, int y, int z){ return x + y + z; };

int main()
{
    assert(curry(sum3)(1)(1)(1) == 3);

    auto plus2 = curry(sum3)(1)(1);
    assert(plus2(1) == 3);
    assert(plus2(3) == 5);
}
```

My implementation idea is as follows: have the `curry` function return an unary function that binds its argument to a future call to the original function, recursively. Call the bound original function on the **"last recursive step"**.

Detecting the "last recursive step" is the problematic part.

My idea was detecting whether or not the current bound function *(during the recursion)* was legally callable with zero arguments, using a `is_zero_callable` type trait:

```
template <typename...>
using void_t = void;

template <typename, typename = void>
class is_zero_callable : public std::false_type
{
};

template <typename T>
class is_zero_callable<T, void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>()())>>
    : public std::true_type
{
};
```

Unfortunately, I cannot seem to find a way to check the correct function for zero-argument "callability" - I need to somehow check if the function **that will be returned** from the currently bound function is zero-callable.

Here's what I've got so far [(godbolt link)](https://goo.gl/snzwTs):

```
template <typename TF, bool TLastStep>
struct curry_impl;

// Base case (last step).
// `f` is a function callable with no arguments.
// Call it and return.
template <typename TF>
struct curry_impl<TF, true>
{
    static auto exec(TF f)
    {
        return f();
    }
};

// Recursive case.
template <typename TF, bool TLastStep>
struct curry_impl
{
    static auto exec(TF f)
    {
        // Bind `x` to subsequent calls.
        return [=](auto x)
        {
            // This is `f`, with `x` bound as the first argument.
            // (`f` is the original function only on the first recursive
            // step.) 
            auto bound_f = [=](auto... xs)
            {
                return f(x, xs...);
            };

            // Problem: how to detect if we need to stop the recursion?
            using last_step = std::integral_constant<bool, /* ??? */>;
            // `is_zero_callable<decltype(bound_f)>{}` will not work,
            // because `bound_f` is variadic and always zero-callable.


            // Curry recursively.
            return curry_impl<decltype(bound_f), 
                last_step{}>::exec(bound_f);
        };
    }
};

// Interface function.
template <typename TF>
auto curry(TF f)
{
    return curry_impl<TF, is_zero_callable<decltype(f)>{}>::exec(f);
}
```

Is my approach/intuition viable? *(Is it actually possible to stop the recursion by detecting whether or not we've reached a zero-arg-callable version of the original function?)*

...or is there a better way of solving this problem?

*(Please ignore the missing perfect forwarding and the lack of polish in the example code.)*

*(Note that I've tested this currying implementation using an user-specified template `int TArity` parameter to stop the recursion, and it worked properly. Having the user manually specify the arity of the original `f` function is unacceptable, however.)*

Comment: You need sfinae augmentation.  Without that your task is impractical; there is no way to soft fail on argument mismatch.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26655685/1774667) for my curry question (and synthesized answer below)

Comment: Clang is happy if you give `bound_f` an explicit return type (`-> decltype(f(x, xs...))`) so that it SFINAEs, and then just use `is_zero_callable<decltype(bound_f)>{}`. GCC isn't, though.

Comment: If you write the generic lambda as a standalone class template instead (with the return-type SFINAE on `operator()`), then it works with both compilers. However, I'm slightly concerned that in the terminal case we may run into the "every valid specialization requires an empty pack => ill-formed NDR" rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The minimal changes required to make this work in Clang is

```
auto bound_f = [=](auto... xs) -> decltype(f(x, xs...))
//                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
     return f(x, xs...);
};

using last_step = std::integral_constant<bool,
                                         is_zero_callable<decltype(bound_f)>{}>;
//                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Explicitly specifying the return type should make it SFINAE-friendly and capable of being detected by `is_zero_callable`. Unfortunately, GCC is unhappy with this, probably due to a bug.

A generic lambda is basically a class with a templated `operator()`, so we can just write it ourselves:

```
template<class F, class T>
struct bound_function {
    F f;
    T arg;
    template<class... Args>
    auto operator()(Args... args) const -> decltype(f(arg, args...)){
        return f(arg, args...);
    }
};
```

Note that I'm imitating the semantics of the generic lambda here and making the `operator()` `const`. A full-featured implementation will likely want to overload on constness and value categories.

Then

```
auto bound_f = bound_function<TF, decltype(x)>{f, x};
```

works in both GCC and Clang, but has a theoretical problem: when *only* `f(arg)` is valid (and not with extra arguments), then instantiating `bound_function` (which instantiates a declaration of its `operator()`) is ill-formed NDR because every valid specialization of `operator()`'s declaration requires an empty parameter pack.

To avoid this, let's specialize `bound_function` for the "no further arguments needed" case. And since we are computing this information anyway, let's just express it in a member typedef.

```
template<class F, class T, class = void>
struct bound_function {
    using zero_callable = std::false_type;
    F f;
    T arg;
    template<class... Args>
    auto operator()(Args... args) const -> decltype(f(arg, args...)){
        return f(arg, args...);
    }
};

template<class F, class T>
struct bound_function<F, T, void_t<decltype(std::declval<const F&>()(std::declval<const T&>()))>> {
    using zero_callable = std::true_type;
    F f;
    T arg;
    decltype(auto) operator()() const {
        return f(arg);
    }
};
```

Then

```
auto bound_f = bound_function<TF, decltype(x)>{f, x};
using last_step = typename decltype(bound_f)::zero_callable;
```

Comment: The quote you implicitly refer to regarding empty packs is presumably defective, at least due to issue 1785 (and its consequences here are unintended, no?).

Comment: @Columbo For CWG 1785, I think the defect is in the first sentence rather than the second. http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue2067 is more on point.

Comment: Weird, I didn't see that one when looking up [temp.res]; it certainly is. What's the fundamental reason such templates are disallowed, anyway?

Comment: @Columbo It's added by [CWG 1231](http://wg21.link/CWG1231). Looking at the examples given there, I can sort of see why they banned them...

Answer (score 1):

under file check. please.

https://github.com/sim9108/Study2/blob/master/SDKs/curryFunction.cpp

```
// ConsoleApplication4.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

// core function
template<typename FN, std::size_t N>
struct curry
{
    FN fn_;
    curry(FN fn) :fn_{ fn }
    {
    }

    template<typename... TS, typename = std::enable_if_t< (N - sizeof...(TS)) != 0, int >>
    auto operator()(TS... ts1) {
        auto fn = [f = this->fn_, ts1...](auto... args) mutable {
            return f(ts1..., args...);
        };
        return curry<decltype(fn), N - sizeof...(TS)>(fn);
    }

    template<typename... TS, typename Z = void, typename = std::enable_if_t< (N - sizeof...(TS)) == 0, int > >
    auto operator()(TS... ts1) {
        return fn_(ts1...);
    }
};

//general  make curry function
template<typename R, typename... Args>
auto make_curry(R(&f)(Args...)) {
    auto fn = [&f](Args... args) {
        return f(args...);
    };
    return curry<decltype(fn), sizeof...(Args)>(fn);
}

//general  make curry member function
template<typename C, typename R, typename... Args>
auto make_curry(R(C::*f)(Args...), C c) {
    auto fn = [f, c](Args... args) mutable {
        return (c.*f)(args...);
    };
    return curry<decltype(fn), sizeof...(Args)>(fn);
}

template<typename C, typename R, typename... Args>
auto make_curry(R(C::*f)(Args...) const, C c) {
    auto fn = [f, c](Args... args) mutable {
        return (c.*f)(args...);
    };
    return curry<decltype(fn), sizeof...(Args)>(fn);
}

//general  make curry lambda function
template<typename C>
auto make_curry(C&& c) {
    using CR = std::remove_reference_t<C>;
    return make_curry(&CR::operator(), c);
}

using std::string;
using std::function;

string func(string a, string b, string c) {
    return "general function:" + a + b + c;
}

struct A {
    string func(string a, string b, string c) {
        return "member function:" + a + b + c;
    };
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    {  //general function curry
        auto c = make_curry(func);

        auto m1 = c("t1")("t2")("t3");
        auto m2 = c("test1")("test2")("test3");

        auto m3 = c("m1");
        auto m4 = m3("m2");
        auto m5 = m4("m3");

        std::cout << m5 << std::endl;
        std::cout << m2 << std::endl;
        std::cout << m5 << std::endl;
    }

    { //member function curry
        A a;
        auto c = make_curry(&A::func, a);

        auto m1 = c("t1")("t2")("t3");
        auto m2 = c("test1")("test2")("test3");

        auto m3 = c("m1");
        auto m4 = m3("m2");
        auto m5 = m4("m3");

        std::cout << m1 << std::endl;
        std::cout << m2 << std::endl;
        std::cout << m5 << std::endl;
    }
    { //lambda function curry
        auto fn = [](string a, string b, string c) {
            return "lambda function:" + a + b + c;
        };
        auto c = make_curry(fn);

        auto m1 = c("t1")("t2")("t3");
        auto m2 = c("test1")("test2")("test3");

        auto m3 = c("m1");
        auto m4 = m3("m2");
        auto m5 = m4("m3");

        std::cout << m1 << std::endl;
        std::cout << m2 << std::endl;
        std::cout << m5 << std::endl;

    }

    auto func3 = make_curry(func);
    std::cout << func3("Hello, ")( "World!", " !hi") << std::endl;
    std::cout << func3("Hello, ","World!")(" !hi") << std::endl;
    std::cout << func3("Hello, ","World!", " !hi") << std::endl;
    std::cout << func3()("Hello, ", "World!", " !hi") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```