# Return a function after parameters are given

Tags: c++

I have a mathematical function `f(x,p)` that depends on argument `x` and parameters `p`. I want to dynamically allocate memory for `p ( void *)` and return a function `g(x)` after the parameters values are fed `f`. How do I implement this in C++? 
More specifically, this is the usage scenario I'm hoping to achieve:

```
 double x;
 p1 = new double[2];
 p2 = new double[2];
 g1 = f(p1)
 g2 = f(p2)
 g1(x);
 g2(x);
```

`g1(x)` and `g2(x)` are functions that compute `f(x,p1)` and `f(x,p2)`, respectively.
Thank you.

Comment: aka currying http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152005/how-can-currying-be-done-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking is effectively to "bind" the first argument (p1) to a function (f) and to have a "placeholder" for the second argument (x). Translating that directly into code in C++11, we could use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

```
auto g1 = std::bind(f, p1, std::placeholders::_1);
g1(x); // calls f(p1, x);
```

The return type of `bind` is unspecified, but if you need to store `g1` somewhere you could store it as a [`std::function<void(double)>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Or you could C++14 it up and write a generic two-argument currier:

```
template <typename F, typename Arg>
auto curry(F f, Arg arg) {
    return [f,arg](auto arg2) {
        return f(arg, arg2);
    };
}

auto g1 = curry(f, p1);
g1(x);
```

Answer (score 2):

In C++11 you can use a lambda to achieve this:

```
double x;
auto p1 = new double[2];
auto p2 = new double[2];
auto g1 = [p1](double d){return f(d,p1)};
auto g2 = [p2](double d){return f(d,p2)};
g1(x);
g2(x);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `std::function`, initialized with a lambda

```
#include <functional>

std::function<void (double)> f(double *p)
{
    return [&](double x) {
        // whatever
    };
}

int main()
{
    double *p = new double[2];

    auto g = f(p);
    g(2);    
}
```

Comment: Note than in C++14 you can return the lambda itself and avoid the cost of `std::function`.

Comment: @Quentin I still like the option of returning an std::function, because it might be simpler for someone not much familiar with the language if you want to carry the function around

Comment: @KABoissonneault you can still sotre the result in a `std::function` if you wish, but forcing it upon those who *are* familiar with lambdas would be a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few conceptual problems with your approach:

1. You can return a function pointer from a function (this is what you describe you want to do here: g1 = f(p1) ), but I think that's overkill here.
2. Since g1(x) = f(x,p1) and g2(x) = f(x,p2) it sounds like all you need is f(x,p1) and f(x,p2);

   ```
   double x;
   p1 = new double[2];
   p2 = new double[2];
   f(x,p1);
   f(x,p2);
   ```

Comment: A simple function pointer wouldn't work, because OP wants an argument binded to the function. As for point #2, the shown code might not correspond to the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void f(double x, double p[2])
{
    std::cout << x << " " << p[0] << " " << p[1] << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    double x = 5;
    auto p1 = new double[2];
    p1[0] = p1[1] = 10;
    auto p2 = new double[2];
    p2[0] = p2[1] = 20;
    auto g1 = std::bind(f, std::placeholders::_1, p1);
    auto g2 = std::bind(f, std::placeholders::_1, p2);
    g1(x);
    g2(x);
}
```